# Is there a python interface to git shortlog?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am trying to get logging information out of git into python. I looked at pygit2 and gitpython, but neither seems to give a high level interface similar to git shortlog. Is there a python library that provides such an interface, or should I just call out to the git executable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you mean `pygit2` was one of the libraries you looked at.  That is a lower level libraries that let you write a higher level library on top of that (it's plenty high-level enough already, is the 3 lines of code to get the basic log output too much?).  It isn't even hard to do what you want - read the [relevant documentation](https://www.pygit2.org/commit_log.html) you could come up with something like:

```
>>> from pygit2 import Repository
>>> from pygit2 import GIT_SORT_TIME
>>> from pygit2 import GIT_SORT_REVERSE
>>> repo = Repository('/path/to/repo')
>>> rev = repo.revparse_single('HEAD').hex
>>> iterator = repo.walk(rev, GIT_SORT_TIME | GIT_SORT_REVERSE)
>>> results = [(commit.committer.name, commit.message.splitlines()[0])
...     for commit in iterator]
>>> results
[(u'User', u'first commit.'), (u'User', u'demo file.'), ... (u'User', u'okay?')]
```

If you want to group the output to be the same as `git shortlog` that's not even hard either, all the data you need is already in the iterator so just use it to put the data into the format you need.